# How to prevent visual studio debugger from accessing the internets?

Tags: c#, c++, visual-studio-2017

Every time I launch my .NET app (.NET 4.7, Win32, WPF) with a debugger, it takes a few seconds, then the following is logged:

```
onecoreuap\inetcore\urlmon\zones\zoneidentifier.cxx(359)\urlmon.dll!66E008B0:
(caller: 66E00728) ReturnHr(1) tid(1ee0)
80070002 The system cannot find the file specified.
```

Only happens when “Enable native code debugging” is checked, but unfortunately, for the current project I do need that native code debugging.

Is there a way to tell debugger to not do whatever it is doing with urlmon.dll, and work offline?

**Update:** wireshark says the timeout is caused by either 40.77.226.250 or 52.166.127.37. Both owned by Microsoft.

Comment: Did you check the settings for automatically downloading dll symbols when they aren't on your system? Disable it?

Comment: @doug Disabled in both IDE GUI and `_NT_SYMBOL_PATH` (the IDE doesn’t allow to uncheck `_NT_SYMBOL_PATH` so I had to modify the environment variable), didn't help.